# How to use Apple Script to control backlit keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, applescript

Is there a way to use an Apple Script to control the brightness of the backlit keyboard on a Macbook?

The backlit keys are the `F5` and `F6`.

**Edit:**

Based on the suggestion of `@Clark` I tried the follow, but it does not work.

```
    NSAppleScript *run = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"tell application \"System Events\" to key code 96"];
    [run executeAndReturnError:nil];
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amit Singh has a chapter on how to do this from C.

https://web.archive.org/web/20200103164052/https://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter10/light/

It'd be easy to compile the sample code on that page and call it from Applescript.

To make Applescript type a function key you have to use the key code. The key codes fore the function keys are:

- F1 = 122
- F2 = 120
- F3 =  99
- F4 = 118
- F5 =  96
- F6 = 97
- F7 = 8
- F8 = 100
- F9 = 101
- F10 = 109
- F11 = 103

To type one do something like this:

tell application "System Events" to key code 96

Comment: I've read through Amit Singh's post and a lot of the functions that he uses are private. I don't think I want to take that route, that's why Apple Script is the best approach. I tried your Apple Script code, but it does not work. Please see the edit in my original question. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah - looks like even though the keys are mapped to the function keys merely sending the function key won't do anything.  That leaves you with the undocumented functions I'm afraid.